# Run java app.jar in background in windows powershell

Tags: java, windows, powershell

I am trying to run a java app in the background.
its simple command -
`java -jar app.jar`

If we run above command on powershell cli - its working fine but not in the background

Few thing i tried

`Start-Job -Command {java -jar .\app.jar}`
Also tried "start command"

it is listing the jobs but its not running the app.
Do we have a way something like "&"

Please suggest

Comment: I guess the correct syntax will be: Start-Job -ScriptBlock  {java -jar .\app.jar}

Comment: Beginning in PowerShell 6.0, you can start jobs using the ampersand (&) background operator.

Comment: In short: In _Windows PowerShell_ (versions up to v5.1), the working directory for `Start-Job` is the user's _Documents_ directory, not the _caller's_ current directory; changing to the caller's / a given directory requires an explicit `Set-Location` call as part of the script block (or via a separate script block passed to `-InitializationScript` ). In _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, the caller's working directory is now inherited by default, and a new `-WorkingDirectory` parameter allows specifying a directory explicitly. See the linked duplicate for details.